# Get Cookie request field with gatling

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling

I am having trouble getting the Cookie field in the request headers.

My code for getting the Set-Cookie field works fine:

`.check(headerRegex("Set-Cookie", "JSESSIONID=(.*)").saveAs("Jsession"))`

Doing `.check(header("Cookie").saveAs("cookie"))` returns empty

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try **.check(header("Set-Cookie").saveAs("cookie"))**

Comment: This should actually be a comment.